# Cart not updating - Magento CE 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, cart

When accessing http the cart does not update until several minutes. This is true both after add to cart which puts you on an empty cart page, or when updating or clearing the cart on the cart page.
On https:// the cart functions normally.
[See link to store](http://silverandcz.com/solid-925-sterling-silver-10mm-men-s-250-figaro-chain-necklace.html)

Comment: Try to disable cache and change theme package to rwd. And Try your cart. if it s work, change package theme by your own and rettry